# checkstyle plugin in netbeans, build.xml target spec for generating convention violations

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, checkstyle, build.xml

I want to improve my `build.xml` file by adding checkstyle to my targets.

I added `checkstyle-5.5-all.jar` to my `lib` folder. I have also added a checkstyle folder containing `checkstyle_checks.xml`.

So far I have this:

```
<taskdef resource="${lib.dir}" classpathref="checkstyle.classpath"/>
<checkstyle config="checkstyle/checkstyle_checks.xml" classpath="${lib}/checkstyle-5.5-all.jar">
    <formatter type="xml" tofile="${checkstyle}/checkstyle_error.xml"/>
    <fileset dir="${src}" includes="${src}"/>
</checkstyle>
```

I get this error:

```
Could not load definitions from resource lib. It could not be found.
```

thats this line:

```
<checkstyle config="checkstyle/checkstyle_checks.xml" classpath="${lib}/checkstyle-5.5-all.jar">
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [checkstyle documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html) the [resource parameter](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html) has to be a properties file and not your lib dir:

```
<taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties"
         classpathref="checkstyle.classpath"/>
```